# Jenkins Version Number Format Substring

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I am using the [Jenkins Version Number Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Version+Number+Plugin).  I have the following    Version Number Format String in my Git/Maven project:

```
#${BUILDS_ALL_TIME} - ${POM_VERSION} - ${GIT_BRANCH}
```

This results in:

[image]

However, I want a **substring** of `GIT_BRANCH` that results in the output:

```
#42 - 1.4.2-SNAPSHOT - master
```

In other words, I just want a `GIT_BRANCH` of `master` and not the remote repository `origin/master`.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in [PR 12](https://github.com/jenkinsci/versionnumber-plugin/pull/12/files) a similar pull request changing the [`VersionNumberBuilder.java`](https://github.com/joemar1988/versionnumber-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jvnet/hudson/tools/versionnumber/VersionNumberBuilder.java#L519-L537).

Similarly, it should be fairly easy to modify that same class to remove `origin/` from any final version string produced by that plugin.

Comment: That example is unclear to me, and as there may be multiple git remotes, it only solves a specific case.  My intention is to suss out the specific format string/regex I can use to modify the variable.